# Android Gradle : Change Version Code for each Build Type

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to change version code based on condition for each Build Variant using the below Gradle Script but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong or is there any other way I can achieve it.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            if (variant.name == 'builTypeName') {
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.versionCodeOverride = 1.1
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Say I have a variant name free and another is paid. I want to have versionCode 1.1 for free and versionCode 1.2 for paid how can I do this based on a condition while checking for each variant?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this answer comes a bit late but for anyone else who's struggling.
The following method should be called inside  `android{...}` in your build.gradle.

important to note that the versionCode can only be an integer value thus `1.1` or `1.2` ist only possible in versionName which is a String value.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'free') {
            output.versionCodeOverride = variant.versionCode * 10 + 1
        }
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'paid') {
            output.versionCodeOverride = variant.versionCode * 10 + 2
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using splits Apk and give the version code

```
splits {
        abi {
            // Enable ABI split
            enable true
            // Clear list of ABIs
            reset()
            // Specify each architecture currently supported by the SDK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
            // Specify that we do not want an additional universal SDK
            universalApk false
        }
    }

     project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi-v7a': 1, 'arm64-v8a': 2, 'x86': 3, 'x86_64': 4]
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                            com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
```

Comment: Say I have a variant name free and another is paid. I want to have versionCode 1.1 for free and versionCode 1.2 for paid how can I do this based on a condition while checking for each variant?